# How to index very large files with Lucene (OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: java, lucene, out-of-memory

How can I index very large text files with Lucene? I have created a minimal example below which hits an OutOfMemoryError when presented with a 2GB text file. I was hoping that providing the FileReader to the Field constructor would allow the input file contents to be streamed, but it seems that is not the case.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String indexDir = "c:/temp/ix";
            SimpleFSDirectory simpleFsDir = new SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get(indexDir), SimpleFSLockFactory.INSTANCE);
            StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
            config.setCommitOnClose(true);
            config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(simpleFsDir, config);

            FieldType storedNotIndexed = new FieldType();
            storedNotIndexed.setStored(true);
            storedNotIndexed.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.NONE);

            FieldType indexedNotStored = new FieldType();
            indexedNotStored.setStored(false);
            indexedNotStored.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS);

            Field idField = new Field("Id", "1", storedNotIndexed);
            Field contentField = new Field("Content", new FileReader("c:/temp/twoGbTextFile.txt"), indexedNotStored);

            Document document = new Document();
            document.add(idField);
            document.add(contentField);

            writer.addDocument(document);

            writer.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField$FreqProxPostingsArray.(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField$FreqProxPostingsArray.newInstance(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.ParallelPostingsArray.grow(ParallelPostingsArray.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField$PostingsBytesStartArray.grow(TermsHashPerField.java:250)
>     at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.add(BytesRefHash.java:271)   at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField.add(TermsHashPerField.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:796)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:447)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:403)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1569)
>     at
>   org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1314)

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: @gaurav I don't think increasing the heap size is really a solution. It just kicks the problem down the road until a bigger file comes along (assuming increasing it even allows this file to index). Preferably I wouldn't need that additional heap space to begin with and can somehow stream the data through.

Comment: how about fractioning the whole process. like close commit and reopen after a given amount of records / processing size?